# Reverse function for libGDX Color.toFloatBits

Tags: colors, libgdx

The method Color.toFloatBits

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color#toFloatBits(float, float, float, float)
```

packs any RGBA color into a single float in libGDX.

Is there any ready-to-use reverse function available?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I found the answer.
It should be

```
new Color(NumberUtils.floatToIntColor(floatBits));
```